# Courting selected items in different Listbox

Tags: vba, listbox

The User must select at most six funds in total from ListBox controls lstLowRisk, lstMedRisk, and lstHighRisk. If the user attempts selecting the seventh fund from any one of the risk categories, prompt a message in a message box. However, I don't know how to court selected items in different Listbox. The variable will change to 0 when I click the item of another Listbox.Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Set the `ListIndex` property of one on the `Click` or `Change` of another - I guess it depends on what on earth you mean by "court"

Answer (score 0):

You can use onExit on each ListBox or OnLostFocus, or MouseDown to increase a global variable CountSelected

```
Public CountSelected As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Private Sub List0_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    For x = 0 To Me.List0.ListCount - 1
      If Me.List0.Selected(x) Then CountSelected = CountSelected + 1
    Next x
    MsgBox CountSelected
End Sub
Private Sub List6_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    For x = 0 To Me.List6.ListCount - 1
      If Me.List6.Selected(x) Then CountSelected = CountSelected + 1
    Next x
    MsgBox CountSelected
End Sub
Private Sub List8_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
    For x = 0 To Me.List6.ListCount - 1
      If Me.List6.Selected(x) Then CountSelected = CountSelected + 1
    Next x
    MsgBox CountSelected
End Sub
```